# Can i import events of other user by using my api in Event Brite

Tags: eventbrite

Hi all I m trying to get the events of other user by using my api key. if that is possible can you please guide me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only access another users events if they are marked as 'public'. In that case you would use the Event Search method (http://developer.eventbrite.com/docs/event-search/) and the organizer's ID.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can if you have the id of the event you are trying to access